# creating a loop for "load" and "save" processes

Tags: r, for-loop, pdftools

I have a `data.frame` (dim: 100 x 1) containing a list of url links, each url looks something like this: `https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do` .

The list (the list is a data.frame called `my_list` with 100 rows and a single column named `col` and is in character format `$ col: chr`) together looks like this :

```
 1 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do"
 2" https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/124/index.do"
 3 "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/125/index.do"

etc.
```

I am trying to import each of these url's into R and collectively save the object as an object that is compatible for text mining procedures.

I know how to successfully convert each of these url's (that are on the list) manually:

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidytext)
library(textrank)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)

#1st document
url <- "https:blah-blah-blah.com/item/123/index.do"

article <- pdf_text(url)
```

Once this "article" file has been successfully created, I can inspect it:

```
str(article)

chr [1:13]
```

It looks like this:

```
[1] "abc ....."

[2] "def ..."

etc etc

[15] "ghi ...:
```

From here, I can successfully save this as an RDS file:

```
saveRDS(article, file = "article_1.rds")
```

Is there a way to do this for all 100 articles at the same time? Maybe with a loop?

Something like :

```
for (i in 1:100) {

url_i <- my_list[i,1]

article_i <- pdf_text(url_i)

saveRDS(article_i, file = "article_i.rds")

}
```

If this was written correctly, it would save each article as an RDS file (e.g. article_1.rds, article_2.rds, ... article_100.rds).

Would it then be possible to save all these articles into a single `rds` file?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `list` is not a good name for an object, <s>as this will
temporarily overwrite the `list()` function</s>. I think it is usually good
to name your variables according to their content. Maybe `url_df` would be
a good name.

```r
library(pdftools)
#> Using poppler version 20.09.0
library(tidyverse)

url_df <-
  data.frame(
    url = c(
      "https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/publications/autism-spectrum-disorder/19-mh-8084-autismspecdisordr_152236.pdf",
      "https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/publications/my-mental-health-do-i-need-help/20-mh-8134-mymentalhealth-508_161032.pdf"
    )
  )
```

Since the urls are already in a `data.frame` we could store the text data in
an aditional column. That way the data will be easily available for later
steps.

```r
text_df <- 
  url_df %>% 
  mutate(text = map(url, pdf_text))
```

Instead of saving each text in a separate file we can now store all of the data
in a single file:

```r
saveRDS(text_df, "text_df.rds")
```

For historical reasons `for` loops are not very popular in the R community.
`base R` has the `*apply()` function family that provides a functional
approach to iteration. The tidyverse has the `purrr` package and the `map*()`
functions that improve upon the `*apply()` functions.

I recommend taking a look at
https://purrr.tidyverse.org/ to learn more.

Comment: Each of these url's end in "index.do" - could this be the problem?

Comment: thank you for your answer! i tried your code and got the following errors: text_df <- 
     url_df %>% 
     mutate(text = map(url, pdf_text))
PDF error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
PDF error (2): Illegal character <21> in hex string
PDF error (4): Illegal character <4f> in hex string ..etc etc etc... PDF error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
PDF error: Couldn't read xref table
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `text`.
x PDF parsing failure.
i Input `text` is `map(url, pdf_text)`.

Comment: One or more of your urls is incorrect. Try encapsulating pdf_text in a function, printing url before you pdf_text it, so you can see which one is failing

Comment: @Noob it doesn't matter what the url is, as long as it returns something that can be parsed by pdf_text

Comment: Choosing names by describing the contents is good advice. But overriding existing names in a small scope is completely unproblematic, and thereʼs nothing wrong with that. (In R in particular you can even continue to use the `list` function even when youʼre using that name for a local variable!)

Comment: @KonradRudolph : I changed the name "list" to "my_list"

Comment: @Dennis : "Try encapsulating pdf_text in a function, printing url before you pdf_text it, so you can see which one is failing " ... can you please show me how to do this?

Comment: @Noob The point of my comment was precisely that this is unnecessary. And `my_list` in particular is *worse* than plain `list`: it’s a completely non-descriptive name. The prefix `my_` is pure visual clutter because it provides no useful information.

Answer (score 1):

So say you have a `data.frame` called `my_df` with a column that contains your URLs of pdf locations. As by your comments, it seems that some URLs lead to broken PDFs. You can use `tryCatch` in these cases to report back which links were broken and check manually what's wrong with these links.

You can do this in a `for` loop like this:

```r
my_df <- data.frame(url = c(
  "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf", # working pdf
  "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pfd" # broken pdf
))

# make some useful new columns
my_df$id <- seq_along(my_df$url)
my_df$status <- NA

for (i in my_df$id) {
  
  my_df$status[i] <- tryCatch({
    
    message("downloading ", i) # put a status message on screen
    article_i <- suppressMessages(pdftools::pdf_text(my_df$url[i]))
    saveRDS(article_i, file = paste0("article_", i, ".rds"))
    "OK"
    
  }, error = function(e) {return("FAILED")}) # return the string FAILED if something goes wrong
  
}
my_df$status
#> [1] "OK"     "FAILED"
```

I included a broken link in the example data on purpose to showcase how this would look.

Alternatively, you can use a loop from the apply family. The difference is that instead of iterating through a vector and applying the same code until the end of the vector, *apply takes a function, applies it to each element of a list (or objects which can be transformed to lists) and returns the results from each iteration in one go. Many people find *apply functions confusing at first because usually people define and apply functions in one line. Let's make the function more explicit:

```r
s_download_pdf <- function(link, id) {
  tryCatch({
    message("downloading ", id) # put a status message on screen
    article_i <- suppressMessages(pdftools::pdf_text(link))
    saveRDS(article_i, file = paste0("article_", id, ".rds"))
    "OK"
    
  }, error = function(e) {return("FAILED")})
}
```

Now that we have this function, let's use it to download all files. I'm using `mapply` which iterates through two vectors at once,  in this case the `id` and `url` columns:

```r
my_df$status <- mapply(s_download_pdf, link = my_df$url, id = my_df$id)
my_df$status
#> [1] "OK"     "FAILED"
```

I don't think it makes much of a difference which approach you choose as the speed will be bottlenecked by your internet connection instead of `R`. Just thought you might appreciate the comparison.

Comment: thank you for your answer! does this first require you to create an object called "articles"?

Comment: You just need a vector. I think you have a `data.frame` called `list` (don't use that name btw) with a column called `col`, which contains the links. In this case to get a vector, simply use `list$col`. You can use that instead of `article` and leave the rest of the code as is.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this! I changed it's name to "my_list"

Comment: I just tried your code and got the following error: 
PDF error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway) PDF error (127): Illegal character <22> in hex string
PDF error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
PDF error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
PDF error: Couldn't read xref table
Error in poppler_pdf_text(loadfile(pdf), opw, upw) : PDF parsing failure.

Comment: do you know what I am doing wrong? thank you

Comment: I think I understand better now where you are coming from and overhauled my answer completely. Have a look and let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are certain url's in your data which are not valid pdf files. You can wrap it in `tryCatch` to handle the errors. If your dataframe is called `df` with `url` column in it, you can do :

```
library(pdftools)

lapply(seq_along(df$url), function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    saveRDS(pdf_text(df$url[x]), file = sprintf('article_%d.rds', x)),
  },error = function(e) {})
})
```

Comment: I think there is a small typo in your code : file = sprintf('article_%d.rds', x)), ... I changed it to (removed the comma)  :  file = sprintf('article_%d.rds', x))

Comment: Unfortunately, this code still did not work. I got errors like : PDF error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
PDF error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
PDF error: Couldn't read xref table , PDF error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway) , Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  cannot open URL, In for (i in seq_along(specs)) { :
  closing unused connection 4

Comment: The final file produced by your code looks like this : [[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL ... 
[[28]]
NULL

[[29]]
NULL

[[30]]
NULL

[[31]]
NULL

Comment: You need to tell us the actual URL's, because it looks like the are *not* actually PDF files.