# R: Convert a "Term Document Matrix" to a "Corpus"

Tags: r, text, nlp, text-mining

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow the instructions from this tutorial over here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidying_casting.html) and learn how to convert a "term document matrix" into a "corpus". However, the explanations provided in this tutorial are unclear to me, and I am not sure how to do this.

Using publicly available Shakespeare Plays, I created the term document matrix as follows:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(pdftools)
library(tidytext)
library(textrank)
library(tm)

#1st document
url <- "https://shakespeare.folger.edu/downloads/pdf/hamlet_PDF_FolgerShakespeare.pdf"

article <- pdf_text(url)
article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
  select(sentence_id, sentence)


article_words <- article_sentences %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence)


article_words_1 <- article_words %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")

#2nd document
url <- "https://shakespeare.folger.edu/downloads/pdf/macbeth_PDF_FolgerShakespeare.pdf"

article <- pdf_text(url)
article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
  select(sentence_id, sentence)


article_words <- article_sentences %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence)


article_words_2<- article_words %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")


#3rd document
url <- "https://shakespeare.folger.edu/downloads/pdf/othello_PDF_FolgerShakespeare.pdf"

article <- pdf_text(url)
article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
  select(sentence_id, sentence)


article_words <- article_sentences %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence)


article_words_3 <- article_words %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")
```

From here, I create the actual "term document matrix":

```
library(tm)

#create term document matrix
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(rbind(article_words_1, article_words_2, article_words_3))))

#inspect the "term document matrix" (I don't know why this is producing an error)
inspect(tdm)
```

Now, I am unsure how to use the instructions from this tutorial (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidying_casting.html) and convert the "Term Document Matrix" into a "Corpus".

Is this how it is supposed to be done?

```
library(quanteda)
d <- quanteda::dfm(tdm, verbose = FALSE)
```

Can someone please show me how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try `quanteda::corpus` to turn the dataframe to corpus.

```
data <- rbind(article_words_1, article_words_2, article_words_3)
corp <- quanteda::corpus(data, text_field = 'word')
```

Comment: thank you! But is there a way to directly convert "tdm" into a "corpus"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you have in the comments of Ronak's answer.

You can't transform a tdm into a corpus as a tdm already has the word counts aggregated in the document and you lost the order of the sentences. Using quanteda you can do several actions on the dfm like replacing words or removing stopwords. See example based on the first shakespeare text to show the process.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(pdftools)

library(quanteda)

url <- "https://shakespeare.folger.edu/downloads/pdf/hamlet_PDF_FolgerShakespeare.pdf"

article <- pdf_text(url)
article_sentences <- tibble(text = article) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>%
  select(sentence_id, sentence)

# added count to simulate a dtm
article_words <- article_sentences %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, sentence) %>% 
  group_by(sentence_id, word) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

# cast into a quanteda dfm
my_dfm <- cast_dfm(article_words, sentence_id, word, count)

# using quanteda's dfm_remove to remove stopwords from a dfm.
my_dfm <- dfm_remove(my_dfm, stopwords())
```

with `dfm_replace` you could replace certain words that might have mistakes and or punctuations you do not want to have. Afterwards you can use dfm_compress to combine features that have the same name into 1 feature.

But you are better of to try to get the original data instead of starting of with a tdm.

Comment: thank you for your reply - the problem is, for my real data": I only have the "tdm" file, I no longer have the equivalents of "article_1", "article_2" and "article_3". I am trying to convert the "tdm" file into a "corpus" so that I can use certain functions from the quanteda library. is this still possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376045/r-error-only-works-with-character-objects : over here, I am trying to remove "stop words" and "tokenize" (both with "quanteda") the "tdm" file, but I can't do it because quanteda is not accepting the "tdm" file. Suppose you already have the "tdm" file - is there a way to "tokenize" and "remove stop words"? thank you

Comment: @Noob, If you already have a tdm, you can just use `as.dfm` on the tdm object. This will turn the tdm into a dfm that you can use with quanteda.

Comment: wow, thank you for this suggestion! i will be sure to try it!

Comment: I just tried the following code (file "a" is the original "tdm") :  b = as.dfm(a) ;
 first_method <- tokens(b) %>%
    tokens_remove(stopwords("en"), pad = TRUE)

Comment: this produced the following error: Error: tokens() only works on character, corpus, list, tokens objects.

Comment: @Noob, you can't transform a dfm into a tokens object. You need to use `b %>% dfm_remove(stopwords("en"))`

Comment: Thank you! I will try this!